# Debootstrap armhd Buster: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: debian, arm, debootstrap

I have a Bash script that creates an .img file that will be copied on SD cards for ARM devices.

The debootstrap command is executed to install a minimal Debian Stretch system (armhf), then a script is executed in chroot (software installation, user creation...).

Recently, as I needed to upgrade on Buster, I changed the debootstrap command distribution parameter to "buster". However I get an error when I try to install software with `bundle install` : SSL error : unable to get local issuer certificate. It turns out even `curl` fails on HTTPS websites with a similar error.

**What I checked**

- ca-certificates is installed, `update-ca-certificates` has been run.
- /etc/ssl/certs content seems similar to the one my computer.

**What I tried**

- `openssl s_client -connect ifconfig.me:443` fails, with `unable to get local issuer certificate`
- `curl -k` obviously works
- `curl --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` works
- I tried to generate an .img file with Buster on amd64, `curl`and `bundle install` works

**How to reproduce the issue**

```sh
touch buster_arm.img
truncate --size=2G buster_arm.img # 1G might not be enough
losetup --show --find --partscan --nooverlap buster_arm.img # should be /dev/loop0
parted --align optimal --script /dev/loop0 mklabel msdos mkpart primary 0% 100%
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/buster_arm
# replace buster by stretch and curl will work
# replace armhf by amd64 and curl will work
debootstrap --arch armhf --variant=minbase buster /mnt/buster_arm https://deb.debian.org/debian/
mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/buster_arm/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/buster_arm/dev/pts
cp "$(command -v qemu-arm-static)" /mnt/buster_arm/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static # bypass architecture (my computer is not on armhf)
chroot /mnt/buster_arm /bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https && update-ca-certificate
curl https://google.fr
```

I am really confused, does anyone have ever face this kind of issue ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was.

It is related to openssl rehash command, performed by update-ca-certificates, that is supposed to create additional links in /etc/ssl/certs.

In my case it fails to create "hash links" (https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1725724.html).

I had to run /usr/bin/c_rehash manually.

It might not be a problem once the system is running on the ARM device, outside the chroot. I will update this answer as soon as I try.